# Cannot run MapReduce job on AWS EMR Spark application

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-emr, mrjob

I am trying to run this example from [mrjob](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/emr-quickstart.html) about running a word count MapReduce job on AWS EMR.

This is the word count code example from `mrjob`:

```py
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

My `mrjob.conf` file:

```
runners:
  emr:
    aws_access_key_id: <my_key_id>
    aws_secret_access_key: <my_access_key>
    region: ap-southeast-1
    subnet: subnet-9a2f90fc
    ec2_key_pair: EMR
    ec2_key_pair_file: ~/.ssh/EMR.pem
    ssh_tunnel: true
```

Run command:

```
python word_count.py -r emr --cluster-id=j-CLUSTER_ID readme.rst --conf-path mrjob.conf
```

My problem is I can run this example if I choose the Application of my cluster is `Core Hadoop`, I cannot run it with the `Spark` application option.

[image]

This is the error when running with Spark EMR cluster:

```
Waiting for Step 1 of 1 (s-xxx) to complete...
  PENDING (cluster is RUNNING: Running step)
  FAILED
Cluster j-CLUSTER_ID is WAITING: Cluster ready after last step failed.
```

I want to run this with `Spark` because my application involves some Spark code and some MapReduce code.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Install Spark option.

Comment: @thebluephantom You mean install Spark option on `Core Hadoop` cluster right?

Comment: Last option shown.

Comment: @thebluephantom I create another cluster with that option but it cannot run the code. I want to run the MapReduce code with this option.

Comment: The first option `Core Hadoop` runs the code normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can create a cluster with Hadoop and Spark installed. In the `Create Cluster - Quick Options` menu, go to `Go to advanced options`.

[image]

Select `Spark` and continue to set up your cluster normally.

After the cluster is created, I can run both MapReduce and Spark applications on this cluster.